# Convert BMP to pure RGB, no color map?

Tags: c, bmp

Using the EasyBMP library (a close adaptation, anyway), I have code to convert a BMP to greyscale.

```
int  monochromeValue (RGBApixel foo)
{
  return (foo.Red+foo.Green+foo.Blue)/3;
}

void setToColor (RGBApixel* loc, int newColor)
{
  loc->Red = loc->Green = loc->Blue = newColor;
}

void greyscaleImage (BMP* image)
{
  int x, y;

  for (x = 0; x < image->Width; ++x)
    for (y = 0; y < image->Height; ++y)
    {
        RGBApixel* pixel = elementAt (image, x, y);
        setToColor (pixel, monochromeValue (*pixel));
    }
}
```

An RGBA pixel is

```
typedef unsigned char  ebmpBYTE;

typedef struct RGBApixel 
{
 ebmpBYTE Blue;
 ebmpBYTE Green;
 ebmpBYTE Red;
 ebmpBYTE Alpha;
} RGBApixel;
```

The code doesn't make it greyscale.  One image is more sepia, and another is mostly greyscale but has some colored highlights.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the color map.  What can I do to make it so that it just uses RGB, without running it through a palette?  (Changing the bit depth is fine, if that'll work.)

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.garybeene.com/code/gbsnippets_gbs_00415.htm) suggests that palettes aren't used on 16+ bit depth images.  So I tried changing the bit depth to 32, and it worked.  24 also worked.  So that seems to be the answer:  use higher bit depths, and it won't need a palette, and it'll instead use the RGB values as they are.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your are being bitten by overflow in your `monocromeValue(...)` function.  As you are adding 3 u8 values together in parenthesis, I don't think the compiler will up-convert the adds to a larger integer type.  I would try:

```
int  monochromeValue (RGBApixel foo)
{
    return ((int)foo.Red+(int)foo.Green+(int)foo.Blue)/3;
}
```

As a test to be sure though.

Comment: Good catch.  It doesn't solve the problem (and if you think about it, it wouldn't -- because the new R, G, and B values would still be identical, even if off.  But I did incorporate your fix -- thanks.